# Chrome Extension: Create a new tab by click a button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am a beginner building a Chrome extension. I have an issue using the function described in the Chrome extension developer doc to make a button to create a new tab in "popup.html". It doesn't work no matter which methods I have tried from Stack Overflow. 
My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Connect For Chrome Extension</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
<script>
function showIndex(){
   var index_url="/index.html",
   chrome.tabs.create({
   url: index_url
   }),
   }
</script>
<body>
<button value="tab" style="width:100px; height:100px;" onclick="showIndex();">Go to  Index</button>
</body>
```

or

```
function createTab() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "/index.html"});
}
<a href="#" onclick="creatTab();">Go to Index</a>
```

Neither option seems to work.

So I wonder whether this function should be placed in background.js? If not, please tell me what's wrong with this code. Thanks in advance!

BTW I changed the URL to `www.stackoverflow.com`. It is still the same---not working.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you spelled create wrong in your HTML.

Your issue is probably that Chrome does not allow you to use "unsafe" code in extensions. [See the documentation here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html). You cannot have javascript in your html. You have to subscribe to the event handler on the DOM element.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Connect For Chrome Extension</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
<body>
<button id="index" value="tab" style="width:100px; height:100px;">Go to  Index</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="indexStuff.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You then need a new indexStuff.js file with this

```
function showIndex() {
    var index_url = "/index.html";
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: index_url
    });
}

document.getElementById('index').addEventListener("click", showIndex);
```

Note, the script tag could be moved to the top if you add an event handler to check when the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
function showIndex(){

   var index_url="/index.html",//why are you using "," instead of ";"?

   chrome.tabs.create({
       url: index_url
   }), //why are you using "," instead of ";"?
}
```

why are you using "," at the end of line, instead of ";"?

Comment: did you add permission for tab api to manifest.json?

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],

Comment: Did you try this?

chrome.tabs.create({url: "/index.html"}, function(){});

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.open(url, title, options)` to open a popup window via JavaScript.

`options` is a string containing one or more of these variables (or empty):

---

`width` width of the window

`height` height of the window

`location` URL visible or not

`status` statusbar visible or not

`menubar` menubar visible or not

`directories` I'm guessing this is the bookmark bar

`toolbar` toolbar (back, home, etc.) visible or not

`resizable` whether or not resizable

`scrollbars` whether or not to enable scrollbars

---

e.g.:

`window.open('http://website.com/popup.html', 'Popup Window', 'width=640,height=480,location=yes,scrollbars=yes');`